# How to use <picture> tag with fallback Mechanism

Tags: css, html, image, image-processing

I am building a site based on the content management system. In my site there is requirement where mobile and desktop Images are different.

I am using picture tag to have the different reolution of image for different devices. The issue is that, there is a requirement where if user would not give the image in any scenario a default image should come in its place.

**CODE:**

```
<picture>
    <source data-srcset="{{prod.desktopImage}}" media="(min-width: 768px)">
    <source data-srcset="{{prod.mobileImage}}" media="(min-width: 320px)">
    <img data-srcset="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" data-src="${properties.placeholderimage}" alt="Not Available" class="lazyload">
</picture>
```

The default image provided by picture tag only include the gaps in the media and not the unavailability of image (as per my understanding).

I have seen several solutions on stackOverflow, but none related to picture tag.

Can anyone help me figure out the same ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this issue the thing is, This solution works perfectly with mostly all browsers other than IOS on mobile. Solution goes like using object tag in place of  in picture tag.

**CODE:**

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="{{prod.desktopImage}}" media="(min-width: 768px)" >
    <source srcset="{{prod.mobileImage}}" media="(min-width: 320px)">
    <source src="${properties.placeholderimage}">
    <object data="{{prod.desktopImage}}" type="image/png">
        <img src="${properties.placeholderimage}" />
    </object>
</picture>
```

Issue that I am getting on the IOS Device is that my fallback is working perfectly fine, but my original images are not getting rendered after first load.

Does anyone have idea what's wrong with this ?